# can someone explain the concept behind: Instance(_obj, bool)

Tags: python

I just learned the story behind python and boolean values representing 'int' values. So when I use the isinstance() I was expecting to receive True // False but this is what returned:

```
i = 3
x = 0
print(isinstance(i, bool))  <-- expecting True
print(isinstance(x, bool))  <-- expecting False

# what returned
False
False
```

can someone explain why? and then explain how it works in this function:

```
def move_zeros(arr):
l = [i for i in arr if isinstance(i, bool) or i!=0]
return l+[0]*(len(arr)-len(l))
```

Comment: Just because a cat has stripes doesn't make it a tabby. Same logic here: code inside `if 3:` runs, but that doesn't make `3` a bool value. Even `1` isn't a bool value, even though it's *numerically equal to* `True`.

Answer (score 1):

`bool` happens to be a subclass of `int`, so *this* is true:

```
isinstance(True, int)
```

But `int` is not a subclass of `bool`, so numbers are not instances of booleans.

Even if they were, the result would be expected to be the same for both `3` and `0`, as they're both instances of the same *type*, and their *value* is irrelevant for an `isinstance` check.

---

`True` and `False` are "special cases" of the numbers `1` and `0`, if you will. `bool` is a narrow subset of `int`, using only two possible integers. The other way around thus makes little sense; you can't express all possible integers with just the values `True` and `False`*.

<sub>* No, bits are something else…</sub>

---

Subclasses work this way:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     pass
... 
>>> class Bar(Foo):
...     pass
... 
>>> isinstance(Foo(), Foo)
True
>>> isinstance(Bar(), Foo)
True
>>> isinstance(Foo(), Bar)
False
```

`Bar` is a subclass of `Foo` and thus any `Bar` instance is—by inheritence—also a valid instance of `Foo`. Not the other way around.

Comment: Understood. if you can though can you explain this code:

Comment: I apologize, I meant the piece of code I just added to the original question.

Comment: What's the input and output of that code and what don't you understand about it?

Comment: The goal of the code is to return the 'array' with all zeros at the end of the list. The piece I don't understand is: Why does the individual use the isinstance(i, bool) when, as you stated above, all numbers would return False (the array is numbers only). it seems more efficient to just use the i!=0 would you agree or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, if the input contained `False` values, those would be regarded as `0` and moved (and turned into `0`). Apparently the author wanted to guard against that and treat all bools as non-zero.

Comment: In general, if you want to understand why code was written a certain way, you should *ask the person who wrote it*.